# Different behaviour from spring-jpa JpaRepository#getOne() method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

spring-jpa with hibernate and mysql 5.7 (platform-bom-1.1.4.RELEASE):

Entity definition:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class ProjectEntity extends MDMBaseDescriptiveEntity
{
}
```

```html
public class ActivityEntity extends MDMBaseDescriptiveEntity
{

    // optional
    @Column(name="project_id")
    private Integer projectId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="container_id")
    private ActivityEntity container;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="container", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn(name="order")
    private List<ActivityEntity> activities = new ArrayList<ActivityEntity>();
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Activity.Type type;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Activity.Mode mode;
    
    private String tag;
...
}
```

Repository Definition:

```html
public interface IProjectDao extends JpaRepository<ProjectEntity, Integer>
{
}
```

```html
public interface IActivityDao extends JpaRepository<ActivityEntity, Integer>
{
    List<ActivityEntity> findByContainerId(int containerId);
}
```

Access non-existence entity by ID:

- ProjectEntity pe = projectDao.getOne(9999999);
  Expected pe == null as the result of the above call, and it is.
- ActivityEntity ae = activityDao.getOne(9999999);
  Expected ae == null as the result of the above call, but ae != null even though all its attributes have the default value. The javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException is thrown when calling getters on ae.

Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: I doubt there is different behavior, but I suggest a read of the docs of `getOne` and `findOne`. In short `getOne` will not hit the database but will return a lazy proxy, it will access the database at the moment you start to call methods on it which in turn will then fail because there is no such object. Hence basically the second situation is what you should expect and not the first one.

Comment: Thanks, findOne should be the method to use. I wish the doc is as clear as you have explained the difference of the two methods.